# How can I prevent from a close method being invoked?

Tags: jpa, ejb, jax-rs

I'm planning to write a business method for those non-container-managed clients such as JRX-RS resources.

```java
@Stateless
public class PersistenceService {

    public <R> R apply(final Function<EntityManager, R> function) {
        return function.apply(entityManager);
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    private transient EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

So that a JAX-RS root resource class uses it like this.

```java
@RequestScoped
@Path("/entities")
public class MyEntites {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id: \\d+}")
    public Response read(final long id) {

        return Response.ok(service.apply(m -> {
            m.find(MyEntity.class, id);
        })).build();
    }

    @Inject
    private transient PersistenceService service;
}
```

The problem is that how can I prevent clients invoking `close()` on specified entity manager?

```java
service.apply(m -> {
    m.close();
    return null;
});
```

Comment: You should add an explanation, why you would like to prevent `close()`?

Comment: @TobiasLiefke Aren't SLSBs for multiple serialized invocation calls? I wonder what happen if injected `EntityManager#close` invoked by mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper around the original entity manager, which ensures that `close()` is never called:

```
public class NoCloseEntityManager implements EntityManager {
  private EntityManager wrapped;
  public NoCloseEntityManager(EntityManager wrapped) {
    this.wrapped = wrapped;
  }

  public void close() { 
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Don't call close()");
  }

  // all other methods from the interface call the wrapped manager:
  public void persist(Object entity) {
    wrapped.persist(entity);
  }
  ...
}
```

That one can you use in your service:

```
@Stateless
public class PersistenceService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private transient EntityManager entityManager;

    public <R> R apply(final Function<EntityManager, R> function) {
        return function.apply(new NoCloseEntityManager(entityManager));
    }

}
```

But I don't know if the effort is worse the result, as `entityManager.close()` isn't called very often - if someone calls it, he will not use it by mistake...

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting another possible solution for anyone's information.

```java
@Stateless
public class PersistenceService {

    private static final Method CLOSE;

    static {
        try {
            CLOSE = EntityManager.class.getMethod("close");
        } catch (final NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
            throw new InstantiationError(nsme.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void constructed() {
        entityManager = (EntityManager) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            entityManager_.getClass().getClassLoader(),
            new Class<?>[]{EntityManager.class},
            (proxy, method, args) -> {
                if (CLOSE.equals(method)) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("i'll find you.");
                }
                return method.invoke(entityManager_, args);
            });
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void destroying() {
        entityManager = null;
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    private transient EntityManager entityManager_;

    private transient EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

Now I can add required methods.

```java
public <R> R apply(final Function<EntityManager, R> function) {
    return function.apply(entityManager);
}

public <U, R> R apply(final BiFunction<EntityManager, U, R> function,
                      final U u) {
    return function.apply(entityManager, u);
}

public int applyAsInt(final ToIntFunction<EntityManager> function) {
    return function.applyAsInt(entityManager);
}

public <U> int applyAsInt(final ToIntBiFunction<EntityManager, U> function,
                          final U u) {
    return function.applyAsInt(entityManager, u);
}

public long applyAsLong(final ToLongFunction<EntityManager> function) {
    return function.applyAsLong(entityManager);
}

public <U> long applyAsLong(
    final ToLongBiFunction<EntityManager, U> function, final U u) {
    return function.applyAsLong(entityManager, u);
}

public double applyAsDouble(
    final ToDoubleFunction<EntityManager> function) {
    return function.applyAsDouble(entityManager);
}

public <U> double applyAsDouble(
    final ToDoubleBiFunction<EntityManager, U> function, final U u) {
    return function.applyAsDouble(entityManager, u);
}
```